# How to keybind helm-projectile-other-file

Tags: key-bindings, helm-projectile

I like using helm-projectile-find-other-file to switch between header and cpp files, for example.  I tried to keybind it to C-c h with the following in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'helm-projectile-find-other-file)
```

When I use the function directly, I get the desired results, and even a message to the effect that: `You can run the command 'helm-projectile-find-other-file' with C-c h`, but if I actually use the keybinding, I get the error: 
    helm-compile-sources: Wrong type argument: sequencep, -1

I guess I have to specify some argument(s?) within the keybinding?  Can someone help me out.  Explanation in addition to a solution is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should update your helm package.